# Opening Excel workbook from vb.net Interop opens without ribbon or menus

Tags: vb.net, interop, excel-interop

[image: Screen shot]

Can't tell if maybe my references are wrong, or what, but when I open a workbook via vb.net, it opens with no menus or ribbons visible, and you can't even access them. It looks like some kind of safe version of Excel. How do I get it to just open normally?

Here's my full block: (relevant import is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
Private Sub ButtonExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExcel.Click
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim oRosterSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    oExcel = New Excel.Application
    oExcel.Visible = True

    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\****.xlsb", [ReadOnly]:=True)
    oRosterSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oRosterSheet.Cells.Clear()

    Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    For Each dc In RosterTable.Columns
        colIndex += 1
        oRosterSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
    Next dc

    For Each dr In RosterTable.Rows
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        colIndex = 0
        For Each dc In RosterTable.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            oRosterSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
        Next dc
    Next dr

    Dim fileName As String = "C:\****.xlsb"
    oRosterSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    oBook.SaveAs(Filename:=fileName)

    oExcel.UserControl = True

    ReleaseObject(oRosterSheet)
    ReleaseObject(oBook)
    ReleaseObject(oExcel)
    GC.Collect()

    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, point of clarity: how come you open it as read only, but then save it over the original with the same filename? Could that readonly argument have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure interop is basically a wrapper around the Office DCOM objects, it's meant to embed the related objects into your own application. It doesn't start the full Office GUI...

Comment: @neophlegm: Because many users will be using the same application and the file will be on a network drive, so I don't want one user to lock other users out of it and potentially throw an error

Comment: @cowbert: I assumed the "oExcel = New Excel.Application" line would bring up the application in full. How else would you do it?

Comment: @cowbert this is not the case - Excel Interop creates a new Excel object and is not easily embedded into an application - it appears like any other Excel window.  OP, Are you sure you are not opening in full screen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out it was opening Excel in "Full Screen" mode, but somehow not maximised. Could be related to the fact that I'm coding on a computer that I'm remoting into. Either way, the below line fixed it:

```
oExcel.DisplayFullScreen = False
```

Comment: This is what I suspected.  Good catch.